# posting on a friend's wall using graph API

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, message

Posting a message on friend's wall, graph API. 
i have the publish_stream extended permission of the user, who is using the application.

the code workds if i want to post sth on my wall.

is there any method to post on wall or send message to all the friends of a particular user??

please help thanks!!

following is the code, but it is not working.

```
 $friends = $facebook->api('/me/friends');
    foreach($friends['data'] as $friend){
            $friendsUserId = $friend['id'];
            echo $friendsUserId . "</br>";
            $result = $facebook->api('/$friendsUserId/feed', 'POST', array(                
                    message' => 'Test Message'                ));
            print_r($result);
        }
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This would perhaps be the way to do it.. (Untested, but I use something similar for my app.)

```
$friends = $facebook->api('/me/friends');

    foreach($friends['data'] as $friend) {
        $facebook->api('/$friend['id']/feed', 'post', array(
                  'message' => 'just a test message',
                  'link' => 'http://site.com',
                  'name' => 'just a test name',
                  'caption' => 'just a test caption',
                  'description' => 'just a test description',
          ));

}
```

This is using the **PHP API**.

Comment: this wont work anymore. see facebook blog for reference. https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/2012/10/10/growing-quality-apps-with-open-graph/

Answer (score 5):

I just did a little testing, and having the permissions of the user, I could indeed post on the user's friends walls via the php api:

```
$facebook->api('/[FRIEND_ID]/feed', 'post', array(
          'message' => 'test message',
          'link' => 'http://google.com',
          'name' => 'test name',
          'caption' => 'test caption',
          'description' => 'test long description',
      ));
```

Answer (score 3):

The publish_stream permission only allows you to publish content on that particular users wall - you cannot post on the wall of all his friends.

Think about it this way - say you have not authorized an application to post anything on your facebook wall but just because one of your friends has given access to his wall - it automatically does not give the application access to publish on the wall of all his friends.

**EDIT**

Rahul, I tried  yesterday night to login as myself and post a message on the wall of one of my friends through my app and surprisingly it worked. I was under the wrong impression that you could not do that. My apologies.

But I'm still not able to figure this out. Let me explain

```
1) I have my real facebook lets call it abc and a test facebook account xyz which I've added as my friend to abc
2) I login into my app using my abc faceboook account and publish a message on the wall of my friend xyz
3) Now I login to facebook.com as abc and it shows on my news feed the message that I published on xyz's wall. When I click on xyz's profile - the message shows up on his wall too. So far so good
4) Now I log out of facebook.com as abc and log back in as xyz. But now I dont see the message that was posted through the app on the wall of xyz.
```

I dont know if there is any kind of delay but I've waited 30 mins but still its not there. But it continues to show when I log in as abc.

I hope you understand what I'm trying to convey here.
I've used the same piece of code like yours - so can you try the above scenarios and see if you experience something similar

Thanks

Comment: cool, but how do i publish on wall of user's friends?? was the main question.

Comment: @rahul - you cannot post on the wall of a user's friends - like I explained - the user has given you permission to publish on his wall - each user has to give explicit permission - so its not possible for you to publish on the wall of a user's friends - This is as far as my knowledge is concerned - I will dig further today and get back to see if its possible

Comment: @rahul - I have updated my answer with the little testing I did yesterday. So i retract my earlier comment of saying its not possible.

Comment: there are spam apps which do that i was a victim of one. there would be some way of doing that. dig and let me know. thanks for your effort.

Answer (score 0):

Gubloo's answer is close.

Posting to a friend's wall is completely possible, but with one caveat, said friend must have also gone through the 'Permissions' dialogue at some point. Meaning, users of your application will be able to post to the wall's of other users of your application.

I'm going to give you the iPhone code, because I don't know php and imagine you'll get the gist. Just replace 'me' with the UID of whatever you are trying to post to, be a page, or a Friend's profile.

`[_facebook requestWithGraphPath:@"/me/feed" 
andParams:params 
andHttpMethod:@"POST" 
andDelegate:self];`

I'm actually curious to know if this would give the user the ability to post on the wall of anyone who uses the application, and not just his friends.

Comment: _“said friend must have also gone through the 'Permissions' dialogue at some point.”_ – what gave you that idea?

Answer (score 0):

$friends = $facebook->api('/me/friends');

```
foreach($friends['data'] as $friend) {
    $facebook->api('/$friend['id']/feed', 'post', array(
              'message' => 'just a test message',
              'link' => 'sample link.com',
              'name' => 'just a test name',
              'caption' => 'just a test caption',
              'description' => 'just a test description',
      ));
```

}
Above code work for me tooooo
Thanks for the post